# Validating password with validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

EDIT: I realized the comments about there not being a difference with :save already covered were correct, and was able to work through some errors. However, it still appears the regex validation is failing for `:password`.

I'm a little confused, and think the problem might be related to there being only `:password_digest` in the table itself, while we use password and `password_confirmation` as attributes in the model. But I'm also guessing Rails has this all worked out and takes care of everything with the `has_secure_password` function.

`validates_format_of :password, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]\z/, :on => :create, :update` fails with the string `password`.

Obviously, this doesn't make sense and matches fine in the console (using `=~` or `.match()`. Also notice if I set `allow_nil: true` for `:password` other tests involving the user start failing (which doesn't make sense, as the password should never be nil anyways).

Comment: Why don't you use `on: :save` which will handle both on create and update.

Comment: Rewrote question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any use case where you need on create and update together if `on: :save` is already there.
For more model callbacks please refer [this.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I see now the problem is elsewhere. Please take a look at the rewritten question if you have a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

> The default behavior for all the built-in validation helpers is to be run on save (both when you're creating a new record and when you're updating it). If you want to change it, you can use on: :create to run the validation only when a new record is created or on: :update to run the validation only when a record is updated.

So, you should not use `:on` option in your validation